# How to extract index of a UiObject element

Tags: reflection, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I have been ramaging through this for a couple of hours now.

I have a `UiObject` element for which I need to find the value of the `index` attribute. The UiObject element only exposes methods to extract information like `Text`, `ContentDescription`, `Bounds`, `Classname`, etc. but not `index`.

I had a similar problem with `resourceID` and I was able to solve it using `Java reflection` to extract the same during runtime. The solution is [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/pull/4068/files#diff-88b2db0717548aa76bee24c09c46a891). I wanted to use a similar approach but `AccessibilityNodeInfo` doesn't expose that information.

Does anyone know of a solution or something similar to retrieve the index information from a UiObject?